# MegaRAID reset "Other Error Count"

Tags: megaraid, megacli

After an un-planned power-cycle of a megaraid controller, 23 of its disks show a single "Other Error Count".

I've extracted the log, and these seems to correspond to the same number of `Unexpected sense .... Sense: 6/29/07` entries. According to [this](http://www.t10.org/lists/asc-num.htm#ASC_29) list, this means `I_T NEXUS LOSS OCCURRED`, and the timestamp matches when the controller was power-cycled.

These aren't media errors, they coincide with the power-outage and rhe drives themselves were not powered down; I'm confident that these errors can be safely ignored, but our Nagios currently is showing 23 errors, and there doesn't seem to be an option in the Nagios plugin to ignore "Other Errors".

smartctl doesn't report these errors, so I think they must be stored in the raid controller, rather that on the drives. I've cleared the event log in desperation, but to no avail.

Is there a way that I can reset this "Other Error Count" on these drives?

Answer (score 0):

I know two ways to reset error counters on megaraid controllers.

- Replace problem disk with online RAID rebuilding;
- Cold start of server;

Try the second one only if you are sure that your data is not damaged
Make sure that you have backup.